# Chopin Op. 9 No. 2 Measure 24 beats

Tags: rhythm, beaming, editions

(1) In my Henle Verlag edition of Chopin's Nocturne Op. 9 No. 2, the **third group** of notes in **Measure 24** has a *single beam* between the first 7 notes and the last 3 notes (see **red arrow**). Other editions seem to simply have 3 beams throughout that group. What difference does that single beam make? How should that red part be played according to this edition?

(2) Also, are my green vertical lines indicating the note correspondence between the two staves correct?)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rhythmic values don't add up in a variant of Chopin's Nocturne op. 9 no 2?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/129866/rhythmic-values-dont-add-up-in-a-variant-of-chopins-nocturne-op-9-no-2)

Comment: Please don't close. This is not the same as that one. That one has small notes printed, not this one. I really want to know how that red part is played. I also asked another question in the parentheses.

Comment: All of the early editions align the C natural in the r.h. with the sixth eighth note of the l.h.; does the Henle edition not say anything about why they've engraved it differently?  Do they cite their sources?

Comment: Which Henle edition is this?  It seems not to be HN 233/HN 185, as that edition has the three beams throughout the whole group, consistent with the editions published in Chopin's lifetime.

Comment: phoog: It the Henle book shown here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/133469/chopin-waltz-in-b-minor-op-69-no-2-measures-1314-different-versions  It doesn't say anything about the source/editions. It seems to be for beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The beaming in the Henle will be closest to how Chopin wrote it. As indicated in the linked question, there is freedom of execution, so the green boxed notes are a fine way to time the left and right hands. Other editions beam differently as a way of suggesting how the editor feels the passage is best played.
2. The green lines are correct.

Comment: Thanks. In the score shown here, is the beat value of that D (where the red arrow is) same as the other notes in the group, or three times the beat value of the other notes? If that single beam is erased, i.e. it becomes seven 3-beam notes followed by three 3-beam notes, would that be the same, or different?

Comment: @GrandAdagio As is explained in the linked question, the notation is not intended to be rhythmically exact. The reason for the single beam is to show that 1) the entire set of 10 notes takes the same time as two eighth notes, and 2) the final three notes should be played as a triplet taking the time of one sixteenth note.

Comment: Aaron, so that single beam is just to connect the two groups; it's not a "quaver"? (I'm thicker than you all assumed. I may be confusing that one line with a quaver (one-beam).) I do understand your point of playing the whole group within the two left hand chords. The way it's written, I thought it meant that D is played a little longer.

Comment: @GrandAdagio Correct, it's not a quaver. It's just there to show that the entire grouping of 10 notes forms one unit.

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron, for answering all my questions to satisfaction!

Comment: "The beaming in the Henle will be closest to how Chopin wrote it": unlikely.  "Other editions beam differently as a way of suggesting how the editor feels the passage is best played": beaming is typically used to show metrical structure, not expression.  My guess is that someone at Henle figured the triplet would be easier to read this way.